# React/D3 - error when creating d3 linechart from local csv using useState - <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,205.40540540…"

Tags: reactjs, arrays, d3.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a linechart in `React` using `D3.js` . The linechart should have `Y` on the y-axis, which is a date column and on the x-axis `X1`. This is a copy of my data in the csv:

[image]

and also posted the sample on kaggle (not sure if this is accessible)

- [link to kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/squishy1/dataui)
- api: kaggle datasets download -d squishy1/dataui

I got it working with a csv via a url , but now that I try to do with a local csv, I can't read in my data the right way. I'm new to Javascript and React, coming from a Python background, it is not really intuitive yet.

In my log I do see that my data gets loaded, but when the visualization want to use it I get the following error:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,205.40540540…".
```

The code that I have so far is:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import csvFile from '../data/Data_UI.csv';


const SimpleLinechart = (props) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const {width, height } = props;

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (data.length > 0) {
      drawChart();
      console.log(data)

    } else {
      getCSVData();
    }
  },[data]);


  const getCSVData = async () => {
    const tempData = [];
  
    await d3.csv(
      csvFile,
      function (d) {
        tempData.push({
          date: d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y")(d.Y),
          value: Number(d.X1),
        });
      }
    );
    setData(tempData);
    console.log(data.date)
  };

const drawChart = () => {

  const test = data.map(function(d) { return d.value });
  console.log(test)

    // create the chart area
    const svg = d3.select('.svg-canvas')
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();

// Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.csv(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
      
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return + d.value; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // set line coordinates
    const line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
      
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line)
 }

return (
    <div>
     <svg className="svg-canvas" width="1000px" height="600px" />
    </div>
    )
}

export default SimpleLinechart;
```

Comment: Don't you intend to set the domain of your x scale with `d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })` rather than `d3.csv(data, function(d) { return d.date; })`?

Comment: @AndrewReid Yes!! I didn't spot it, thank you so much, I finally have a line in my chart :)